# Finding a list of agriculture unique to Catalina Island

Tags: guides, guidebooks, southern-california

I'm trying to find a list of plants that are unique to Catalina Island. In particular one species of vine that exists on the mainland as a regular vine.

However, when exposed to the nature of Catalina island, this vine has adapted and become "a tree". I remember seeing this tree, and the descriptive explanation following it, but can't identify the species.

Does anyone know where I can find a list of plants, unique to Catalina island (or perhaps other regions of interest)?

Comment: The [Catalina Conservancy](https://www.catalinaconservancy.org/index.php?s=wildlife&p=plant_species) has a list of plant species that are found on the island, but it's not sorted into types of plants.

Comment: @mkennedy has given you the correct web site and, if you drill down, it lists the [seven endemic species of flora](https://www.catalinaconservancy.org/index.php?s=wildlife&p=endemic_species)

Comment: @Dorothy if it's true that the plant was introduced to the island than it's not endemic, unfortunately.

Comment: VTC: too broad: without more detail or pictures, it is impossible to identify a plant to grows as a vine on the mainland and is a tree on the island. OP has not returned since positing the question.

Comment: Seems better suited to [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) or [Gardening.SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about ecology, not travel.

Answer (score 1):

As Catalina Island is in fact known to have six unique plants and there is a place of interest, namely **Wrigley Memorial & Botanical Gardens**, I find the question fits to travel.

The [unique species are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Catalina_Island_(California)#Flora):

- Catalina manzanita (Arctostaphylos catalinae)
- Catalina mahogany (Cercocarpus traskiae)
- Catalina dudleya (Dudleya hassei)
- St. Catherine's lace (Eriogonum giganteum var. giganteum)
- Santa Catalina bedstraw (Galium catalinense ssp. catalinense)
- Santa Catalina Island ironwood (Lyonothamnus floribundus ssp. floribundus).